# How to set the max-width of a container with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to have `services-bar__title` and `services-bar__services` to have a `max-width` of `1024px` so that I get the normal flexbox behaviour for the container as formatted below, but the list doesn't expand further than `1024px` if the viewport is wider. I tried setting the container widths and max-widths, but it doesn't seem to work as expected as the container doesn't stay centered anymore, any ideas?

```css
.services-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 20rem;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 -3rem 8rem rgba(#000, 0.5);
}

.services-bar__title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.services-bar__services {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="services-bar">
  <div class="services-bar__title">
    test title
  </div>
  <div class="services-bar__services">
    <div class="services-bar__services_1"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="services-bar__services_2"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="services-bar__services_3"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="services-bar__services_4"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. So if I'm understanding  your query correctly, you want the services-bar_services_1 up to 4 to be able to expand to a width past 1024px?

Comment: Yeah your question isn't very clear - what you are trying to do and I see no max-widths in your code attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that, you don't need to make your `services-bar` a `flex`, rather only keep `services-bar__title` and `services-bar__services` as `flex`.

Use `justify-content: space-around;` in the `services-bar__services` to distribute the items throughout the container. And for the `services-bar`, set `max-width: 1024px;` as well as `margin: 0 auto;` so that it remains in center and don't go beyond `1024px`.

Try this out:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.total-width {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.width-1024px {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.services-bar {
  height: 20rem;
  box-shadow: 0 -3rem 8rem rgba(#000, 0.5);
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.services-bar__title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.services-bar__services ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="total-width"></div>
<div class="width-1024px"></div>

<div class="services-bar">
  <div class="services-bar__title">
    test title
  </div>
  <div class="services-bar__services">
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="services-bar__services">
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="services-bar__services">
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="services-bar__services">
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yostrh8n/25/

Comment: margin: 0 auto, this what was missing here. You got it. Do you know why this is needed since the parent container already has "justify-content: center;", i.e.".services-bar".

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you want to expand the service to 100% up to 1024px. Right?

To do so, u need to set the default width to 100%, and set the max-width to 1024px.

```css
.services-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 -3rem 8rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  max-width: 1024px;
  
  .services-bar__title {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .services-bar__services {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .services-bar__services_1,
  .services-bar__services_2,
  .services-bar__services_3,
  .services-bar__services_4 {}
```

```html
<div class="services-bar">
  <div class="services-bar__title">
    test title
  </div>
  <div class="services-bar__services">
    <div class="services-bar__services_1"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="services-bar__services_2"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="services-bar__services_3"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="services-bar__services_4"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly is this what you meant? Then you can use media queries to solve your problem. I set `max-width to none` on devices larger than 1024px.

```css
.services-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 20rem;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 -3rem 8rem rgba(#000, 0.5);
  }
  .services-bar__title {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    background: red;
    max-width: 1024px;
  }
  .services-bar__services {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    background:green;
    max-width: 1024px;
  }

  
 @media only screen and (min-width : 1024px) {
  .services-bar__services {max-width: none;}
  .services-bar__title {max-width: none;}
}
```

```html
<div class="services-bar">
  <div class="services-bar__title">
    test title
  </div>
  <div class="services-bar__services">
    <div class="services-bar__services_1"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="services-bar__services_2"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="services-bar__services_3"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="services-bar__services_4"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a container to expand beyond 1024px.  I assume the 1024px is the  width of a parent element which means you can play with the following code to expand the child element beyond the parent element.

```
width: 100vw;
margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
```

This will expand the width to the Viewport Width (100vw - being 100% of the viewport).  The problem is that the margin will be set to the parent elements' margin.  To fix this you have to play with the left margin.  In order to be responsive you need to use calc.